# C# SOAP client: sending generic XmlNode request

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I have a C# project where I added a SOAP service reference, using the integrated visual studio functionality (right click -> add -> service reference)

The client classes are generated correctly without errors. However, the various methods of the service only accept a generic `System.Xml.XmlNode` as an input, rather than a structured object.

This should not be a problem in theory, since I have the complete XML file with the query that I need to perform. So I tried doing it like this:

```
NSIStdV20ServiceSoapClient client = new NSIStdV20ServiceSoapClient();
var getAllDataFlowQuery = File.ReadAllText(@"Query\get_all_dataflow.xml"); //file containing the query
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(getAllDataFlowQuery);
var dataStructures = client.QueryStructure(doc); //this method accepts a System.Xml.XmlNode as parameter
```

However, this doesn't work, throwing

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 'Error due to a non correct client message'
```

I thought initially that the query was incorrect, but I tried to perform the exact same query using `SoapUI` and it works perfectly! I even tried doing it with the exact XML returned by `doc.InnerXml` (just to be sure che `XmlDocument` object was not modifying the XML) and it works.

So basically it's only when calling the method from C# that it doesn't work.

If you want to try it out yourself, the service is freely accessible, the WSDL is here:

> http://sdmx.istat.it/SDMXWS/NsiStdV20Service.asmx?WSDL

and you should try to call the `QueryStructure` method with the following payload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/sri/service/2.0"><soapenv:Header /><soapenv:Body><web:QueryStructure><!--Optional:--><web:Query><RegistryInterface xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message SDMXMessage.xsd" xmlns="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message" xmlns:common="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/common" xmlns:compact="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/compact" xmlns:cross="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/cross" xmlns:generic="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/generic" xmlns:query="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/query" xmlns:structure="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/structure" xmlns:registry="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/registry" xmlns:utility="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/utility" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Header><ID>JD014</ID><Test>true</Test><Truncated>false</Truncated><Name xml:lang="en">Trans46302</Name><Prepared>2001-03-11T09:30:47-05:00</Prepared><Sender id="BIS" /></Header><QueryStructureRequest resolveReferences="false"><registry:DataflowRef /></QueryStructureRequest></RegistryInterface></web:Query></web:QueryStructure></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

As I said, this works perfectly in SoapUI, but doesn't work when calling the client method from C#

Comment: Have you tried `client.QueryStructure(doc.DocumentElement)`?

Comment: @dbc: yes, but that wasn't the issue, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that the client generated by visual studio, even tho it accepts a XmlNode as input, creates some of the required outer structure itself (to be precise: all the outer nodes with the `soapenv` and `web` namespaces).

Which means I had to strip down the input XML to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><RegistryInterface xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message SDMXMessage.xsd" xmlns="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message" xmlns:common="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/common" xmlns:compact="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/compact" xmlns:cross="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/cross" xmlns:generic="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/generic" xmlns:query="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/query" xmlns:structure="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/structure" xmlns:registry="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/registry" xmlns:utility="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/utility" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Header><ID>JD014</ID><Test>true</Test><Truncated>false</Truncated><Name xml:lang="en">Trans46302</Name><Prepared>2001-03-11T09:30:47-05:00</Prepared><Sender id="BIS" /></Header><QueryStructureRequest resolveReferences="false"><registry:DataflowRef /></QueryStructureRequest></RegistryInterface>
```